# Stress Amplitude Calculation in Haigh Diagram beside Limit Line

Tags: applied-mechanics, stresses, fatigue

I want to use the Haigh diagram for mean stress and stress amplitude correction using SODERBERG limit line. All I can find is the relation between stress amplitude and mean stress described **at** the limit line:
$$
\frac{\sigma_m}{\sigma_Y}+\frac{\sigma_a}{\sigma_W} = 1
$$
with $\sigma_Y$ as yield stress and $\sigma_W$ as fatigue limit for completely reversed loading ($R=-1$).
How can I calculate the stress amplitude $\sigma_{Wi} $ at $R=-1$ when data points for stress cycles with $\sigma_{mi}$ and $\sigma_{ai}$ are not at the limit line but beside the line?

I'm not sure if I need to shift the limit line parallel to the point (e.g. `D1` and `D2`) to do the stress amplitude correction. Or is the line to be rotated at $\sigma_Y$ to intersect with the stress cycle point?

Thanks a lot!

[image]